# Consuming Odata Service on windows phone 8 on the Localhost

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-8, wcf-data-services

I was able to add my Odata service service reference on my windows phone app from the localhost but i couldn't get a collection of data when i'm trying to consume it knowing that when i use Northwind service reference i can get the needed data, i have even checked the service version , i thought that it's a problem of compatibility? but i stil not sure what is going on here because i havn't got any error. i'm trying to get the service response using fiddler but i don't know if i'm in the right direction or not , please help??? i'm using Odata service V3 on visual studio 2010 and i'm trying to consume it from VS express 2012 on IIS (localhost).!!! :(( (the same project was working fine on the server and on LinqPad4 on the localhost)

this is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using TestConsumeWebService.Resources;
using TestConsumeWebService.Northwind;
using System.Data.Services.Client;
using TestConsumeWebService.DataService;

namespace TestConsumeWebService
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private static readonly Uri _rootUri =
            new Uri("http://localhost:88/DataService.svc/");

        //// Define the typed DataServiceContext.
        //private DataEntities _context;

        // Define the binding collection for Customers.
        private DataServiceCollection<Table> _customers;

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);

        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           var _context = new DataEntities(_rootUri);
           Customers = new DataServiceCollection<Table>(_context);

            // Specify an OData query that returns all customers.
            var query = from cust in _context.Table
                        select cust;

            // Load the customer data.
            Customers.LoadAsync(query);
        }
        public DataServiceCollection<Table> Customers
        {
            get { return _customers; }

            private set
            {
                // Set the Titles collection.
                _customers = value;

                // Register a handler for the LoadCompleted callback.
                _customers.LoadCompleted += OnCustomersLoaded;

                // Raise the PropertyChanged events.
            }
        }


        // Handles the DataServiceCollection<T>.LoadCompleted event.
        private void OnCustomersLoaded(object sender, LoadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Make sure that we load all pages of the Customers feed.
            if (Customers.Continuation != null)
            {
                Customers.LoadNextPartialSetAsync();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

and this is my Odata Service Code:

```
public class DataService : DataService<DataEntities>
    {
        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
            // Examples:
            config.UseVerboseErrors=true;
             config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
             config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code to get help.

Comment: ok i have added my code !! please help!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments of this API. This API is only for siverlight.

```
    // Summary:
    //     Asynchronously loads the collection by executing a System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery<TElement>.Supported
    //     only by the WCF Data Services 5.0 client for Silverlight.
```

In order to query customers in Windows phone. You can try following code.

```
       var _customers = new DataServiceCollection<Table>(_context);

        // Specify an OData query that returns all customers.
        var query = (from cust in _context.Customer
                    select cust)
                    as DataServiceQuery<Table>;

        var ar = query.BeginExecute(null, null);
        ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        response = query.EndExecute(ar) as QueryOperationResponse<Table>;
        _customers.Load(response);
        var continuation = response.GetContinuation();            

        while (continuation != null)
        {
            var ar2 = _context.BeginExecute<Table>(continuation, null, null);
            ar2.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
            var response2 = _context.EndExecute<Table>(ar2) as QueryOperationResponse<Table>;
            _customers.Load(response2);
            continuation = response2.GetContinuation();
        }
```